Jesus earthly crucified by earthly rulers
1 Corinthians 2:8  the rulers of the sage some claim that Jesus was crucified demons could you refute their arguments and prove Jesus was crucified by it by Pontius Pilate in Roman rulers

Question is unclear; please rephrase + substantiate.

One way of re-phrasing could be to ask about the identity of "the rulers of this age".

You are invited to check out the [Tour], [Help], [Ask], and [Answer] to understand what a good/valid question consists of. SE sites expect a certain level of quality and clarity in both questions and answers.

As the question remains unclear, it is likely to be closed. Before that happens, let me answer according to how I understand it, and if I am mistaken, you could add a comment to explain why.
I take the question to ask, Was Jesus' earthly crucifixion done by earthly rulers (Pontius Pilate) or were invisible demons behind it all? 1 Corinthians 2:8 is referred to but not quoted. You may note that in the column to the right of the question is a list of 'Related' questions, one such being "What does it mean of 1 Corinthians 2:8?
1 Corinthians chapter 2 has Paul preaching Jesus Christ, and him crucified, according to the hidden wisdom of God, and not according to the wisdom of this world, or the princes of this world. Paul explains that if the princes of this world (earthly men who ruled, like Pontius Pilate) understood the wisdom of God, they would never have had Christ crucified. For then, they would have known that Christ is the Lord of glory. That is what verse 8 shows.
The gospel of Christ, which the Christians preached, was about the revealing of the mystery of God - how he had determined before the creation of the world to show his righteousness in dealing with mankind's sin through his sinless Son dying as the only perfect sacrifice for sin there has ever been.
The Bible shows that it was God who caused Christ to suffer, die, and be resurrected in triumph over sin, death, and the devil:

"Yet it pleased the Lord to bruise him; he hath put him to grief; when
thou shalt make his soul and offering for sin, he shall see his seed,
he shall prolong his days, and the pleasure of the Lord shall prosper
in his hand." Isaiah 53:10 A.V.

It was God's will being carried out at Golgotha. Had the demons known that that was what the crucifixion would achieve, they would have done everything in their demonic power to prevent it! But the mystery of the ages only became revealed through the preaching of the good news of Jesus Christ, in light of his resurrection. God's righteous wrath was poured out on his beloved, sinless Son as he became sin on the cross. He had to die that way, for God's law states that "without the shedding of blood, there is no sacrifice for sin." Hebrews 9:22 Thus Christ's one, perfect sacrifice for sin achieved what the Godhead had planned from before the creation of the world, to deal with sin once and for all. It happened according to the foreordained purposes of God, and human rulers were used as visible agents of execution.
